# IdentityServer4 Multiple API access, single token

Tags: identityserver4

We have several API's that we'd like to grant access to a client via client credentials flow.  The flow would go something like this.

1. Client gets a token from is4 based on some scope
2. Client hits first API with token
3. Client needs to hit second API with same token.

Authorization of the token at the API endpoint seems to only work when the APIResource matches the APIName in the authentication parameters.

How do you set up APIResource/Scopes such that this scenario can be accommodated?

Comment: Does your client have scopes for the both APIs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I had the chance to play a bit with your case and have a solution.

So, as you know, the client credentials flow, works based on (except the clientid and client secret) ApiResoirces/Scopes.

Your API's, in their authentication configuration, have:

- `ApiName` - for .NET Core API
- `RequiredScopes` - for .NET Framework API

Depending on your case, you have to set them.

These are the APIResources/Scopes, that your IDS client should have, in its allowed scopes/api resources (`Client.AllowedScopes`).

Then, when requesting the client credentials, from the token client, you should pass as scope, a string, containing the both scopes/apiresources separated with interval (`tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("api1 api2");`)

Then the access token, that you receive in the response, will be valid for calls for both of your api's.

You also have the second option, in which both your api's use one and the same scope/apiresource, but I don't think that this is a good approach at all.

Comment: This is what was screwing me up.  I didn't know that you could pass multiple scopes in tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync().  The intellisense has it as string scope (singular).  Much appreciated!

Comment: ATTENTION, Using same `access-token` to access two different `resource api` is dangerous. because first `resource api` can call the other 'resource api' 's end-points and vice versa. Try to use separate access token for each `resource api`. Far better solution is to prevent this in `Identity provider server` in first place, But i just don't know how.